# Problem booting Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: boot

I recently tried to install the latest version of Ubuntu on my computer, substituting Windows 7. The installation ran smoothly, but now when I try to boot the system I receive this error message:

```
reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media in selected boot device and press a key
```

The only thing I can do is run the live version via USB, which is what I am doing right now. I looked for a solution in some forums and I decided to run [boot-info](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info) and post the result of the diagnosis [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10724753/).

Comment: Is the machine in UEFI mode?  Those are the only bootloaders present.

Comment: Does it work now?  If not, could you try `boot-repair`?

Answer (score 0):

You have no bootloader installed on `/dev/sda`. The bootloader may have been installed on the EFI partition on `/dev/sda1` but this partition seems to be not active.
You could try to set the partition active using the `cfdisk` command in a terminal window.
Hint: as the poster of this question pointed out, one must use parted / gparted to edit GPT partitions.

**Attention**: it turns out in the comments that this answer was completely misleading.
If you however need some information about installing Ubuntu on an UEFI enabled system, you may read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: This looks like a UEFI machine, so the bootloaders are in the EFI partition, sda1.

Comment: So what could I do? Should I "toggle bootable flag on current partition"? Sorry but I am not experienced in these kind of things. I currently have only sda1 in the partition list, sda1, should I toggle the "bootable" option?

Comment: Yes, if the bootable option is not set, then do it.

Comment: But are you sure that this is the right disk as seen on top of the cfdisk window?

Comment: I do not know if this is related, but doing sudo cfdisk I firts recieve the message "warning!! Unsupported GPT (GUID partition table) detected. Use GNU parted.". Is there a way to upload images here to show you some screenshots?

Comment: Then you must use gparted to set the partition active. Use gksu gparted

Comment: As for the screenshots, i don't think you can upload images right here. But you could use some file upload service and then post the link here.

Comment: here is the screenshot of cfdisk http://postimg.org/image/erq1dacud/853cb1a9/

Comment: okay, so cfdisk only sees one partition so don't change anything here but rather use gparted. Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/ew324dni7/ec550825/ here I am with gparted, how can set the partition active and which one should I set? sda2?

Comment: Hm...sda1, which is the EFI partition, is listed already having the boot flag. That's weired. Could it be, that only the boot order of your drives is wrong?

Comment: Well I tried to change the order, but the thing is, if I boot without inserting the USB it should boot using EFI partition I think. Should I try to reinstall everything or something like that?

Comment: Please check if your BIOS is set to boot the disk in UEFI mode. See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI 
Also, there are some instructions how to install Ubuntu on UEFI enabled systems. Sorry, i could not help you further because i for myself am not using EFI. I always disable it in my BIOS before installing.

Comment: Could you please both edit your original question and answer so someone else doesn't have to read all the comments that didn't work???  ;-)  If done, drop me a line @Fabby and I'll have a look!

Comment: @Fabby i have edited my answer to show that it was misleading. Hope this is adequate.